# GoogLeNet Inception v4 is different from the paper?

Tags: tensorflow

paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07261.pdf

code:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v4.py

---

line 91:

```
branch_2 = slim.conv2d(branch_2, 224, [7, 1], scope='Conv2d_0d_7x1')
```

in the paper is [1, 7]

---

line 216:

```
branch_0 = slim.conv2d(net, 192, [3, 3], stride=2, padding='VALID',
```

in the papter stride is not equal to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a minor mismatch:

```
  branch_2 = slim.conv2d(branch_2, 224, [7, 1], scope='Conv2d_0d_7x1')
```

instead of using sequence of convolutions {[1, 7], [7, 1], [1, 7], [7, 1]} it has {[7, 1], [1, 7], [7, 1], [1, 7]}. I would be surprised if it had an effect on the accuracy, but might still be worth creating an issue on github.

Regarding the second one:

```
branch_0 = slim.conv2d(net, 192, [3, 3], stride=2, padding='VALID',
```

They clearly forgot or omitted (for the sake of getting a better picture) the stride on the illustration. That layer is supposed to reduce the spatial resolution since it takes 71x71x192 as input and produces an output of 35x35.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And line 86 seems really wrong, in the paper is [1, 7]

Comment: @YoonPer the pair of convolutions [7, 1] [1, 7] is an optimization trick of reducing number of parametrs for a full [7, 7] conv. First 2 have 2*(7*1+1) paras vs 1*(7*7+1). From that point of view it doesn't matter which one comes first as long as you use 2 of them after each other

Comment: I know this, but in the paper Figure 5 branch 3, It's a pair of convolutions [1, 7][1, 7], And the code is [1, 7] [7, 1], I don't know whose fault it is.

Comment: Right, that should not be like that. The illustration must be wrong